# mysql query by having timestamp along both the axis (i.e) in both columns and rows

Tags: mysql, sql

Hi consider a table like this 
[image]

Now i need an output like this

[image]

this is my requirement. i just gave 3 registration dates days here. consider there are N number of registration dates and validity dates. how to write a query for this. Thanks for helping me.

Comment: I don't think this can be done with a query. Do a search for cross tab query. One result is this (though I've never done this, I just do it via code): http://rpbouman.blogspot.com/2005/10/creating-crosstabs-in-mysql.html

Comment: Truly sad that MySQL doesn't support Pivots.  That's the exact tool you need to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

What you seek is often called a crosstab. Here is a sample that would produce the results you want:

```
Select registrationDate
    , Sum( Case When ValidityDate = '2010-10-25' Then 1 Else 0 End ) As `2010-10-25`
    , Sum( Case When ValidityDate = '2010-10-26' Then 1 Else 0 End ) As `2010-10-26`
    , Sum( Case When ValidityDate = '2010-10-27' Then 1 Else 0 End ) As `2010-10-27`
From MyTable
Group By registrationDate
```

If what you want is to dynamically build the columns, you are seeking a dynamic crosstab. The SQL language in general is not designed around dynamic column generation and thus this cannot be done natively in MySQL without using dynamic SQL. Instead, you should build this query in your middle tier or report engine.